# How to show all items if params are empty in xsl?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to choose from cd base all cd's with parameters year and artist if they are set, but if not - I need to show all cd's. I know that I can set * symbol to show all but I tried to make this way

```
<xsl:param name="year" select="*" >
<xsl:param name="artist" select="*" />
```

if parameters are not set it does not work, it shows nothing.

```
<xsl:for-each select="cd">
  <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortBy]" order="{$order}" />
   <xsl:if test="year = $year">
    <xsl:if test="artist = $artist">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="album"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="studio"/></td>
        <td width="100px" height="100px"><xsl:apply-templates select="link"/></td>
      </tr>
     </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 the usual way is to define the default value as an empty string, using

```
<xsl:param name="artist" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="year" select="''"/>
```

then in a predicate you use e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="cd[(not($artist) or $artist = artist) and (not($year) or $year = year)]">...</xsl:for-each>
```